# Do you know another method for saving and retrieving user input text?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

These are `XAML` codes:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="164" Width="302">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Height="23"  Margin="10,12,0,0" Name="TextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" />
    <Button Content="Store Text" Height="23"  Margin="10,49,0,0" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" />
    <Button Content="Retrieved Stored Text" Height="23" Margin="10,88,0,0" Name="Button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

These are `vb.net` codes:

```
Class MainWindow 

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    My.Settings.mySett = TextBox1.Text
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub


Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    MessageBox.Show(My.Settings.mySett)
End Sub

End Class
```

This is a [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvID1.png):

Here is my question:

I am already using above codes in order to save and retrieve user input text.

But this method doesnt work when my application is moved to another directory.

I mean if user moves my application to another directory, then the Setting is lost.

So, is there any other method for saving and retrieving user input text?

Comment: Are they moving just the .exe file?  To my knowledge, the settings are stored in the _yourappname.exe.config_ file.  Are they moving that file along with your .exe?

Comment: Yes, they are moving that file along with my exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also can use Registry to save the value.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TextRetriever", "SavedText", TextBox1.Text, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    MessageBox.Show(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TextRetriever", "SavedText", ""))
End Sub
```

Comment: Try opening the application from debug folder as administrator.

Comment: You didn't like saving it in a file in your app folder or in temp folder. Also you didn't like saving it in registry. I think there isn't another way.
You must choose a folder to save it ( doesn't matter if it's temp or another one from your decision )

Comment: Another solution that might success is to try another registry root instead of **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE**

Comment: It's not difficult but you search for something that can't be removed and doesn't need admin permissions.
Does the last solution of trying another registry root work for you ?

Comment: What do you mean by **looking for a solution inside my app** ?

Comment: There is no mean by storing in in the app. Even your app variables are saved in RAM which is temporary memory, so you can save in a file or registry. I think there is no other way. If you found another way, I'd be so glad to hear it.

Comment: Youssef13, do you know how to save image to Registry?

Comment: I really didn't try that, but you may try to encode it to base64 string and save it.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is not standalone, I'd recommend creating a file at the `Application.StartupPath` and load the text when the form loads. In this way, no matter where the user keeps the application, which is shortcut, the file will always be in the installed directory.

This always works.

Comment: How about if user cut the application and paste the same directory?

Comment: Well in that case, you can save the file in desktop and hide it or in a `Temp Folder`

Answer (score 0):

You may save the text in the Temp folder and retrieve it like the following

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    IO.File.WriteAllText(IO.Path.GetTempPath & "storedText", TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    MessageBox.Show(IO.File.ReadAllText(IO.Path.GetTempPath & "storedText"))
End Sub
```